# How do I do a "regression" on a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, regression, data-analysis

I have a differential equation for a model of uptake and depuration of a contaminant. The model looks like this:
$$\frac{dC}{dt}=k_u-(k_d+g)\cdot C(t)$$
I have estimates of the depuration rate $k_d$ and the growth rate $g$, and I have the concentration at times $t=0$ and $t=6$. I would like to use those to estimate the uptake rate $k_u$ and, ideally, find a confidence interval for $k_u$.

So far my best bit is to run a simulation with an estimated $k_u$, see if I end up at the right value, adjust it up or down, see if it helps, and repeat until I get a decent best guess. I could probably automate this iterative process in MatLab. It just feels a bit too home-made.

Any other ideas?

(Note that in this case, a regression is not strictly necessary, as I already estimated the other parameters. It could just be the nonlinear equivalent of connecting two dots with a straight line.)

Comment: What are your data ? $t_i$ and $C(t_i)$ ?

Comment: Do you want to use purely numeric framework for this or you don't mind that this problem has some sort of closed form solution?

Comment: I've got estimates of $C(0)=0$, $C(6)\approx 1.6$ (or something), $k_u\approx-0.1$, and $g\approx-0.05$, I believe. Not sure I get @Evgeny's question. Do you suggest estimating a $C(t)$ equation, like a polynomial fit or something?

Comment: Are the k's and g constant? If so then you can solve in closed for to get the differential equation out of the problem.

Comment: Seems that me and @Ian suggest almost the same thing: put the differential equation out of the question by solving it (which is very simple here). Then you get a concious formula for which you can perform a regression given enough data. And of course you can plug estimates of other parameters into this formula to get the estimate for $k_u$.

Comment: Oh. You're right. How delightfully dull.
Suppose I couldn't?

Comment: As I understand from titles of some papers, it's possible in principle and it seems to be called "dynamical systems learning". I hadn't looked at these papers further than at their titles, so I don't know whether my advice is useful or not.

Comment: If you are forced to actually work with the differential equation, and especially if you have more data than you have free parameters, then you have an inverse problem for an ODE, which is quite a bit harder than just a "forward" problem for an ODE.

Comment: Yeah, I've been kinda sorta working with that before, in my first couple years of university. We steared clear of the gritty details.

Comment: Forward and backward Euler, Runge-Kutta, Adams-Moulton, Adams-Bashforth, Gaussian quadrature, etc?